# NVD3 stacked bar chart transition not working?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm in a bit of a pickle with regards to a NVD3 multi column / stacked bar chart.

I've got pretty much all of the chart working except from when you select the stacked option, nothing happens.

The image below shows it in action with stacked selected and it staying as a grouped chart.

**EDIT:**

Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kd82ep7p/1/

The code i'm using is below -

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
      .rotateLabels(0)      //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
      .transitionDuration(300)
       .showControls(true)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
      .groupSpacing(0.24)    //Distance between each group of bars.

      ;

chart.reduceXTicks(false).staggerLabels(true).groupSpacing(0.3);

chart.x(function(d) { return d.x; });
chart.y(function(d) { return d.y; });

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(negative_test_data)
       .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);



    return chart;
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you put your code on a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so someone can have a better look at the code and the data.

Comment: Edited now has JSFiddle

Comment: In you data try putting `y` values as integer not string. If you look at the console it throws and error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined `

Comment: Have a look at this [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/r6o8k1aw/), with some sample data

Comment: What do you mean as integer?

Comment: Think I know what you mean now, here is the updated version, still not working http://jsfiddle.net/kd82ep7p/3/

Comment: having the same issue with simple line chart, any solution?

Comment: This problem is similar to yours. The problem is in the data: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887945/nvd3-stacked-bar-chart-option-not-working>