# NVD3 stacked bar chart option not working

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to create bar chart using nvd3 data. Grouped option is working fine but when I select Stacked it gives following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined(…)

JSON format is as below.

```
var test =  [

     {
         "key":"A",
         "values":
             [
                {"x":"2016-11-24","y":34},
                {"x":"2016-11-25","y":10}
              ]
     },
     {
         "key":"B",
         "values":
             [
              {"x":"2016-11-25","y":15}
             ]
     },
     {
         "key":"C",
         "values":
             [
              {"x":"2016-11-28","y":11}
              ]
     },
]
```

javascript code:

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
      .rotateLabels(0)      //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
      .transitionDuration(300)
       .showControls(true)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
      .groupSpacing(0.24)    //Distance between each group of bars.

      ;

chart.reduceXTicks(false).staggerLabels(true).groupSpacing(0.3);

chart.x(function(d) { return d.x; });
chart.y(function(d) { return d.y; });

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(test)
       .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);



    return chart;
});
```

I have tried it but can't find answer. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in the JSON data. Basically the `values` array should have the same length across all data series. In your example when nvd3 transforms data into stacked view it expects to have a 2nd element of the values array.

```
{
 "key":"B",
 "values":
  [
      {"x":"2016-11-25","y":15}
  ]
}
```